# What's the intended way working with angular and ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular

I've just startet my first project with angular in combination with ruby on rails. There isn't that much documentation outside. After some research I'm confused about this combination.

In a normal angular project you would server the content and the style via angular. But in rails this doesn't seems to work out of the box, so there must be an other intention.

Is it really meant to serve the templates and styles using rails views and than add only the client logic using angular?

Comment: Keep learning. It'll make sense in time. If you're just starting to learn Rails, then the majority of the tutorials are going to be based on MVC (Model View Controller). In this context the View is just going to be JSON output, and Angular is an **external** client fetching that JSON. Rails is a great back-end for an Angular project.

Answer (score 1):

Angular is not really meant to work with any kind of backend templating. Angular is meant for Single Page Applications (SPA) that work on their own. Usually, you would have one or more APIs to communicate with your Backend (usually via REST, sometimes GraphQL). Templatiting, Styling and Bindings should be done by Angular alone.

So in your case you would only supply a REST Based API using Rails and do all of the frontend work in your Angular application, which in turn communicates only via REST with your Rails Backend.